# In JS, how to have multiple drawings at different speeds?

Tags: javascript, animation, drawing, intervals

I’ve got drawings of planets that revolve around the sun. They rotate fine, but they need to be positioned accurately. They move at the same speed so it doesn’t look realistic.

I would like to know how to make some planets swing a lot faster than others but they’re all in the same animation function and trying to make several animation functions just causes errors.

Here's my relevant code:

```
function rotate_point(pointX, pointY, originX, originY, ang) {
    ang =  Math.PI / 180.0;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(ang) * (pointX-originX) - Math.sin(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originX ,
        y: Math.sin(ang) * (pointX-originX) + Math.cos(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originY 
    };
}



, Venus: {
            render: function(){
                ctx.beginPath();
                gravityVenus = rotate_point(gravityVenus.x, gravityVenus.y, dynamicSunX, dynamicSunY, angleOfSun); //the positions are dynamic based on what the canvas height and width are
                ctx.arc(gravityVenus.x,gravityVenus.y ,7, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,165,0,1)"; 
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
        , Mercury: {
            render: function(){
            ctx.beginPath();
            gravityMercury = rotate_point(gravityMercury.x, gravityMercury.y, dynamicSunX, dynamicSunY - 2, angleOfSun);
            ctx.arc(gravityMercury.x,gravityMercury.y ,5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(119,136,153,1)";  
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            }

    function animate(){
    background.render();
    Solarsystem.Neptune.render();       
    Solarsystem.Uranus.render();
    Solarsystem.Saturn.render();
    Solarsystem.Jupiter.render();   
    Solarsystem.Mars.render();
    Solarsystem.Earth.render();
    Solarsystem.Venus.render();
    Solarsystem.Mercury.render();       
    Solarsystem.Sun.render(); 
}

 var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000/60); //this sets the speed for everything in the Solarsystem array.
```

I’ve found a snippet from somewhere that might help you but didn’t help me adjust , I tried to play with it but I couldn’t get it working. Here it is.

```
var time = new Date();
ctx.arc( ((2*Math.PI)/60)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/60000)*time.getMilliseconds() );
enter code here
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use Math.random() ?

Comment: Once I find out how to alter the speed of every planet, I don't want the speed for each planet to be random, I want them the speeds to kinda match how they really spin in real life

Comment: well, you could change the speed they are moving by chaging the angle (/frame) you are rotating the planets. maybe my bultiplying `angleOfSun` with a factor, but then on the other side you completely ignore the passed `ang` in `rotate_point()` and rotate everything by 1° / frame; you have to fix a few things in your code.

Comment: angleOfSun = 0 degrees. I don't get what ang does, I'm afraid. That particular code was written for me because I'm not at that level yet. What would I need to change about it, specifically?