# Positioning a rotating object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, orbit

I'm creating an interactive solar system canvas in Javascript.

Planets rotate around the sun with a trigonometric function. This particular code was written for me, so I don't know how it works exactly.

In order for the planets to be positioned right so they make a full spin around the sun I can only position their x axis without touching their y axis. But whenever I refresh the page, they start at very unrealistic positions. This could be fixed via either knowing how to properly position them, or change the speeds of the planets.

Here's most of the relevant code:

```
    function initCanvas(){

    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    var dynamicSunW = 25;
    var dynamicSunH = 0;
    var dynamicSunX = (ctx.canvas.width * .5) - (Math.PI* 1 * .5);  
    //dynamicSun is always at dead center of canvas
    var dynamicSunY = (ctx.canvas.height * .5) - (dynamicSunH * .5);
    var angleOfSun = 0;

    var posMercuryX = (ctx.canvas.width * .5) - (Math.PI* 1 * .5) - 50;  
    var posMercuryY = (ctx.canvas.height * .5) - (dynamicSunH * .5) + 20;
    var gravityMercury = {x: posMercuryX, y: posMercuryY };

    var posVenusX = (ctx.canvas.width * .5) - (Math.PI* 1 * .5) - 50;
    var posVenusY = (ctx.canvas.height * .5) - (dynamicSunH * .5) + 46;
    var gravityVenus = {x: posVenusX, y: posVenusY };
    /*these variables with lots of calculations behind them simply represent
    dynamic positions based on canvas width and height so that whenever i change
    the canvas size, the positions will still be the same in relation to the size
     */     

    //this code was not written by, the trigonometric function
        function rotate_point(pointX, pointY, originX, originY, ang) {
            ang =  Math.PI / 180.0;
            return {

                    x: Math.cos(ang) * (pointX-originX) - 
Math.sin(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originX ,
                    y: Math.sin(ang) * (pointX-originX) + 
Math.cos(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originY 
                };
            }


            //an array of each planet with their own position, size and style
        var Solarsystem = {     
        Venus: {
                render: function(){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    gravityVenus = rotate_point(gravityVenus.x, gravityVenus.y, 
dynamicSunX, dynamicSunY, angleOfSun);
                    ctx.arc(gravityVenus.x,gravityVenus.y ,7, 0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,165,0,1)"; 
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
        , Mercury: {
            render: function(){
            ctx.beginPath();
            gravityMercury = rotate_point(gravityMercury.x, 

gravityMercury.y, 
dynamicSunX, dynamicSunY - 2, angleOfSun);
                ctx.arc(gravityMercury.x,gravityMercury.y ,5, 0, 2*Math.PI);

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(119,136,153,1)";  


            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
        , Sun: {
        render: function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,51,1)";  
        ctx.save(); //store ctx so it can  be later reused 
        ctx.shadowColor = 'yellow';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 70;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(dynamicSunX, dynamicSunY, dynamicSunW, 

dynamicSunH, Math.PI*2, true);


    ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore(); //ctx at time of save
```

And here's how I set the animation interval

```
function animate(){
        background.render();
        Solarsystem.Neptune.render();       
        Solarsystem.Uranus.render();
        Solarsystem.Saturn.render();
        Solarsystem.Jupiter.render();   
        Solarsystem.Mars.render();
        Solarsystem.Earth.render();
        Solarsystem.Venus.render();
        Solarsystem.Mercury.render();       
        Solarsystem.Sun.render(); 
    }

     var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000/60);
```

PS: I've asked a different question on how I can speed each planet up. I'm still waiting for an answer. If you know how to, please send me an answer to that one too! 
[In JS, how to have multiple drawings at different speeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549466/in-js-how-to-have-multiple-drawings-at-different-speeds)

Comment: You should start by understanding the code you're working with. Ask the author, ask specific SO questions, but before you know what it does you won't succeed at extending it.

Comment: I do understand my code, it's one aspect of it that I don't understand, and that's not because I haven't tried it. I can't wrap my head around it, it's mostly the math that does it